# Scan Source Code for Licenses Used

Tags: open-source, licensing

I remember encountering a commercial software that scanned a project's source code and provided a list of all the different software licenses it used. That is, it would find all the third party code used in a project and give their licenses (Apache, GPL, ...).

Can anyone provide a link to such a program?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the one I remembered:

http://www.blackducksoftware.com/protex - Protex by Black Duck.

The key term to use in google, as I learned the hard way, is "Software Compliance Management".

Answer (score 2):

[FOSSology](http://www.fossology.org/home) is a GPL-licensed tool for analyzing OS licensing. It's main capability is to do pattern matching against uploaded source code and find matching licenses.

Answer (score 1):

I know about a Ruby library called [Ohcount](http://labs.ohloh.net/ohcount).